# Property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type - how to add foreign keys in migration scenario of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, migration

I have this class with only the foreign key references:

```
public class Device
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "key")]
    [Key]
    public Guid Key { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeviceType")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Model")]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ModelType Model { get; set; }
}
```

I get an error while running the command

```
 Add-Migration -Name "DeviceMigration"
```

Error is:

> The property or navigation 'DeviceType' cannot be added to the entity type 'Device' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'Device'.

This is my context class content

```
 public class MyContext: DbContext
 {
     public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
     { }

     public DbSet<DeviceType> DeviceTypes { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: For anyone getting this while using `Scaffold-DbContext`, double check to make sure you don't have two identical foreign keys on your table. I thought mine were unique, but started getting this error when I upgraded EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your `Device` model class as follows:

```
public class Device
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "key")]
    [Key]
    public Guid Key { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("DeviceType")]   
    public Guid DeviceTypeId { get; set; } // I assumed primary key of your `DeviceType` entity is `Guid`

    [ForeignKey("ModelType")]  
    public Guid ModelTypeId { get; set; } // I assumed primary key of your `ModelType` entity is `Guid`


    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }


    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ModelType ModelType { get; set; }
}
```

Now generate the migration. Hope everything will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

For my situation, I misused ForeignKey attribute:

```
[IgnoreMap]
public long? PLCalculationMasterId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PLCalculationMaster"), IgnoreMap, IgnoreDataMember]
public PLCalculationMaster PLCalculationMaster{ get; set; }
```

whereas it should have been:

```
[IgnoreMap]
public long? PLCalculationMasterId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PLCalculationMasterId"), IgnoreMap, IgnoreDataMember]
public PLCalculationMaster PLCalculationMaster{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all solutions provided above fails, just delete the migrations folder and recreate the migrations.
This error may arise due to visual studio cache references.

One could alternatively rename the property on the target entity.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which was caused by wrongly specifying the primary keys of the table.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34668380)